# JAX-RS Application subclass injection

Tags: java, jersey, jax-rs, jersey-2.0

I'm writing custom JAX-RS 2.0 application (under Jersey 2.3.1) which holds some data for use by all the resources.

```java
public class WebApp extends org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig {
    public WebApp() {
        packages("my.resources.package");
    }
}
```

(I could use API's `javax.ws.rs.core.Application` as well, the described result is the same)

Then I inject the object into a resource

```java
@Path("test")
public class Test {
    @Context
    Application app;

    @GET
    @Path("test")
    public String test() {
        return "Application class: " + app.getClass();
    }
}
```

However, the result of a call is

```
Application class: class org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig$WrappingResourceConfig
```

which makes me use some ugly tricks like

```java
if (app instanceof WebApp) {
    return (WebApp) app;
} else if (app instanceof ResourceConfig) {
    return (WebApp) ((ResourceConfig) app).getApplication();
}
```

My understanding of JAX-RS 2.0 spec section 9.2.1:

> The instance of the application-supplied `Application` subclass can be injected into a class field or method parameter using the `@Context` annotation. Access to the `Application` subclass instance allows configuration information to be centralized in that class. Note that this cannot be injected into the `Application` subclass itself since this would create a circular dependency.

is that *application-supplied `Application` subclass* is mine `WebApp`, not JAX-RS implementation-specific wrapper.

Also, changing this fragment

```java
    @Context
    Application app;
```

to this

```java
    @Context
    WebApp app;
```

causes `app` to be `null`, due to `ClassCastException` during context injection, so the declared type doesn't matter.

Is it a bug in Jersey or my misunderstanding?

**UPDATE:** I checked the behaviour under RESTEasy 3.0. The injected object is my `WebApp`, without any wrappers. I'd call it a bug in Jersey.

Comment: Can you show us the `ClassCastException`?

Comment: Sorry, can't detect it now. But I'm sure it was present when I was debugging the issue (possibly still with Jersey 2.2) and the exception was due to mapping `ResourceConfig$WrappingResourceConfig` to `WebApp` of mine. The exception was being caught and the inection was not being made.

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't seem like a bug. According to JAX-RS 2.0 spec you can inject `Application` into your resource classes (for example) but it does not say anything about directly injecting custom extensions of the `Application`. Not sure what your use-case is but you can register custom HK2 [binder](https://hk2.java.net/2.2.0-b19/apidocs/org/glassfish/hk2/utilities/binding/AbstractBinder.html) that will allow you to inject directly `WebApp` into resources:

```
public class WebApp extends org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig {
    public WebApp() {
        packages("my.resources.package");

        register(new org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.binding.AbstractBinder() {
            @Override
            protected void configure() {
                bind(WebApp.this);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: "*The instance of the application-supplied Application subclass*" from the quoted spec. specifically says about my `WebApp`.

Comment: As for my use-case, I want to develop a JAX-RS implementation-agnostic way of injecting an application into resources. The HK2 binder looks almost perfect, leaving Glassfish dependency only in Application subclass' code.

Comment: I think the meaning of the sentence is that you can inject into `Application` type and you'll get an instance of your subclass but not that you can directly inject your subclass into `WebApp` field.

Comment: That's not the case. As I wrote in the question, when I define field `@Context Application app` the result is the same: `app` has Jersey wrapper object, not my subclass object.

Answer (score 1):

I too have encountered this using Jersey 2.4.1.

FWIW: I agree it seems like a bug according to the spec para 8.2.1. The statement *"The instance of the application-supplied Application subclass"* seems perfectly clear.

I have an alternative workaround that doesn't involve glassfish.hk2 but still concentrates the Jersey-specific code in the Application-derived class.

```
public class MyApp extends ResourceConfig {
...
    static MyApp getInstance( Application application) {
        try {
            // for a conformant implementation
            return (MyApp) application;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            // Jersey 2.4.1 workaround
            ResourceConfig rc = (ResourceConfig) application;
            return (MyApp) rc.getApplication();
        }
    }
...
}

public class MyResource {
...
    @Context Application application;
    ...
    SomeMethod() {
    ... MyApp.getInstance( application);
    }
}
```

Hope this is useful.

Comment: Of course I now notice that the original poster found the "getApplication()" workaround which was the core of my supposed contribution.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be fixed in a later version og Jersey. The same approach works for me with Jersey 2.16 at least. My injected Application object is of the correct subclass without any wrapping whatsoever.

Edit: Or maybe the version is irrelevant after all. Please see the comments to this answer.

Comment: Could you please send your code for the injected Application subclass, resource into which it is injected and web.xml? I still have wrapping occur in Jersey 2.17

Comment: @pwes I did a quick test with your `WebApp` and `Test` classes from your original post, only changing package/class names, and it outputs the name of the unwrapped `WebApp` class. Maybe the difference lies in the web server and how it is set up. I use Jetty and do this: `JettyHttpContainerFactory.createServer(uri, new WebApp());`. I don't use a web.xml file.

Comment: Seems like the wrapping is done in the `forApplicationClass()` methods in Jersey's ResourceConfig.java. [Searching their GitHub repo for this method name](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=forApplicationClass) gives some interesting results. For example, in JerseyServletContainerInitializer.java, which appears to be used for Servlet 3.x deployment, the method is used in several code paths. My guess is that the wrapping you are observing is caused by your method of deployment and how Jersey has chosen to implement that method.